# Solr default field value refresh on atomic update

Tags: solr, solr6

I have a date field with default value `NOW` in my Solr schema:

```
<field name="ActionTimestamp"
       type="date" indexed="true"
       stored="true"
       default="NOW"
       multiValued="false"/>
```

Is there any way to refresh the `ActionTimestamp` value automatically on every atomic update? So I need it to be updated with `NOW` value on every atomic update. Now I have to set this field explicitly in the code.

Solr version is 6.4.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with Atomic Updates you only change the fields you need. If you are changing other fields other than AtomicTimestamp, it is as designed that this field does not get updated.

If you absolutely want the value to be set automatically, just reindex the whole doc (no Atomic Update), and NOW value will be used.

Or, do as you are doing now, and set the time on the value yourself.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!